# MongoDB: How to map faceted results into a single object of keys and values

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, aggregation-framework

I'm trying to build a query which will give me an idea of what equipment people will require at a given allocated time. I do this by taking a set of teams, and summing the list of equipment, at any given time to determine how much equipment is in use.

I have a set of things which look like this:

```js
  const teams = [
    {
      id: 'a',
      start: date('2020-04-30-10T17:00:00.000Z'),
      end: date('2020-05-01T05:00:00.000Z'),
      equipment: [
        { id: 'balls', quantity: 2 },
        { id: 'bats', quantity: 4 }
      ]
    },
    {
      id: 'b',
      start: date('2020-04-30-10T20:00:00.000Z'),
      end: date('2020-05-01T08:00:00.000Z'),
      equipment: [
        { id: 'balls', quantity: 2 },
        { id: 'bats', quantity: 4 }
      ]
    }
  ]
```

Then I have a query which I build by looping over an array of times-spans and building facets from them, so the facet keys are dynamic:

```js
       const { facet, project } = occurrences
      .reduce(({ facet, project }, { key, fromDate, toDate }) => {
        facet[key] = [
          {
            $match: {
              start: { $not: { $gt: toDate } },
              end: { $not: { $lt: fromDate } }
            }
          },
          {
            $unwind: '$equipment'
          },
          {
            $group: {
              _id: '$equipment.id',
              quantity: { $sum: '$equipment.quantity' }
            }
          },
        ]
        return facet
      }, {})

    const equipmentTotals = await db
      .collection('teams')
      .aggregate([
        {
          $facet: facet
        }
      ])
      .toArray()
```

This results in output as follows:

```json
{
  "202004301700": [
    {
      "_id": "bats",
      "quantity": 2
    },
    {
      "_id": "balls",
      "quantity": 4
    }
  ],
  "202004302000": [
    {
      "_id": "bats",
      "quantity": 2
    },
    {
      "_id": "balls",
      "quantity": 4
    }
  ],
  "202004302300": [
    {
      "_id": "bats",
      "quantity": 2
    },
    {
      "_id": "balls",
      "quantity": 4
    }
  ]
}
```

What I would want the result to look like, is:

```json
{
  "202004301700": [
    equipment: {
      balls: 2,
      bats: 4
    }
  ],
  "202004302000": [
    equipment: {
      balls: 2,
      bats: 4
    }
  ],
  "202004302300": [
    equipment: {
      balls: 2,
      bats: 4
    }
  ]
}
```

Or any reasonable equivalent, where the list of equipment totals is an object containing balls and bats, rather than an array of each equipment type.

I've tried tens of solutions from docs, stackoverflow, and other places which involve $map, $reduce, $arrayToObject, and a variety of other things. To no avail.

This must be possible. What am I missing?

Comment: Your expected output is not a valid JSON format. `equipment` must be inside an object like this `"202004302300": [ { equipment: { balls: 2, bats: 4 } } ]`. Also in your output `bats` are 2 and `balls` are 4 but in expected output `bats` are 4 and `balls` are 2? Is that correct?

Comment: Ah yeah I missed some braces. I basically want an object for each of my facets which has the totals in. The totals should match - I messed up my expectation! sorry :)

bats: 2, balls: 4, for each.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add below two stages after your `$group` stage inside `facet`

```js
{
    $group: {
        _id: null,
        "equipment": {
            $push: { k: "$_id", v: "$quantity" }
        }
    }
},
{
    $addFields: {
        "equipment": {
            $arrayToObject: "$equipment"
        }
    }
}
```